# Integrating ckEditor and kcFinder Not Showing Browse

Tags: jquery

I edited the config.js file in CKEditor as instructed to integrate KCEditor but when I click the images button and then the Upload Tab, the only thing showing is the label "Send it to the server" and the blue button saying "Send it to the server." The browse button and the text box that shows on the KCFinder demo is missing.

The CKEditor folder and the KCEditor folder are both in \assets\js.

Any help is appreciated!!!

Jon

Here is the config.js code:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    config.toolbar = 'ppm';

    config.toolbar_ppm = [
    { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold', 'Italic','Underline', '-','RemoveFormat'] },
    { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight' ] },
    //{ name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format','Font','FontSize','TextColor' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Flash','Link','Unlink','Anchor','-','Iframe' ] },
    { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'tools', items : [ 'SpellChecker', 'Smiley' ] },
    { name: 'document', items : ['Source'] }        
    ];

    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '../kcfinder/browse.php?type=files';
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '../kcfinder/browse.php?type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '../kcfinder/browse.php?type=flash';
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '../kcfinder/upload.php?type=files';
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '../kcfinder/upload.php?type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '../kcfinder/upload.php?type=flash';
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have not done a proper install. [Read this here](http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/docs/install), and make sure you don't have the component disabled which is set to disabled by default (for reasons explained on the website).